# drawCircle on ImageView wrong coordinates

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I'm trying to draw a circle on ImageView. Circle is drawing, but with wrong coords.

```
 protected void onImageClicked(float x, float y, ImageView image) {
        if (diff.isDifferenceClicked((int)x, (int) y)){

        BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bm= bmd.getBitmap();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);

        image.setImageBitmap(bm);}

    }
```

x and y is `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` 
and the circle is drawing higher and more to the left side of Bitmap.

Comment: Can you do a System.out.println(x+","+y); before drawCircle and let me know what you got?

Comment: I get coords of the place i clicked. if im clicking in the top left corner i have 0 0. Coords is right but the place is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with bitmap size. 
Original size of file was right. But after this

```
 BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bm= bmd.getBitmap();
```

size was extended for 15-20%